# Cypher grouping relational nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I have a cypher database with directors and movies
The directors have person attributes like: name, surname, date of birth etc.
The movies have attributes like: name, duration, date of release, tags

Tags are an array attribute that contains movie tags.

What I want to do is return the director attributes with an aggregate array of tags for all movies he directed.
Live example of nodes:

Nodes:

```
(:Movie {name: "Titanic", duration: 192, date: 1997, tags: ['Drama', 'Romance']})
(:Movie {name: "Aliens", duration: 137, date: 1986, tags: ['Action', 'Sci-Fi']})
(:Movie {name: "Terminator", duration: 107, date: 1984, tags: ['Action', 'Sci-Fi']})
(:Director {name: "James", surname: "Cameron", birthdate: "16 Aug 1954"})
```

The structure that I want to have as a return is:

```
{
  name: 'James',
  surname: 'Cameron',
  birthdate: '16 Aug 1954',
  tags: ['Action', 'Sci-Fi', 'Drama', 'Romance']
}
```

The query below works fine for a single director with multiple movies but as soon as I create a second director with other movies all of the tags are merged inside one array, is there a way to collect only the tags belonging to a single director?

```
 MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:directed]-(d:Director)
UNWIND m.tags AS tags
RETURN {
    tags:COLLECT(DISTINCT tags),
    director: COLLECT(DISTINCT d)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you simply avoid the `collect` for the directors.
I would write the following statement:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:directed]-(d:Director)
UNWIND m.tags AS tags
WITH d, COLLECT(DISTINCT tags) AS dtags
RETURN {
    tags: dtags,
    director: d
}
```

Comment: beat me to it:)

Comment: That made perfect sense, thanks